# complex merge pandas numpy with Aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to merge two dataframe and calculate the 3 columns witch an avergage of the past observation for a GIVEN ID .

Here is an example :

```
contracts_data = np.array([
                        [1, '2015-01-01', 15000],
                        [2, '2015-01-01', 1500],
                        [1, '2015-08-01', 16000],
                        [2, '2015-08-01', 1800],
                        [1, '2015-10-01', 17000],
                        [1, '2016-01-01', 18000],
                        [1, '2016-03-01', 20000]])


    historique_data = np.array([[1, '2015-01-01'],
                        [2, '2015-01-01'],
                        [1, '2015-02-01'],
                        [2, '2015-02-01'],
                        [1, '2015-03-01'],
                        [2, '2015-03-01'],
                        [1, '2015-04-01'],
                        [2, '2015-04-01'],
                        [1, '2015-05-01'],
                        [2, '2015-05-01'],
                        [1, '2015-06-01'],
                        [2, '2015-06-01'],
                        [1, '2015-07-01'],
                        [2, '2015-07-01'],
                        [1, '2015-08-01'],
                        [2, '2015-08-01'],
                        [1, '2015-09-01'],
                        [2, '2015-09-01'],
                        [1, '2015-10-01'],
                        [2, '2015-10-01'],
                        [1, '2015-11-01'],
                        [2, '2015-11-01'],
                        [1, '2015-12-01'],
                        [2, '2015-12-01'],
                        [1, '2016-01-01'],
                        [2, '2016-01-01'],
                        [1, '2016-02-01'],
                        [2, '2016-02-01'],
                        [1, '2016-03-01'],
                        [2, '2016-03-01'],
                        [1, '2016-04-01'],
                        [2, '2016-04-01'],
                        [1, '2016-05-01'],
                        [2, '2016-05-01']])

    historique_data_expected = np.array([[1, '2015-01-01', 15000],
                        [2, '2015-01-01', 1500],
                        [1, '2015-02-01', 15000],
                        [2, '2015-02-01', 1500],
                        [1, '2015-03-01', 15000],
                        [2, '2015-03-01', 1500],
                        [1, '2015-04-01', 15000],
                        [2, '2015-04-01', 1500],
                        [1, '2015-05-01', 15000],
                        [2, '2015-05-01', 1500],
                        [1, '2015-06-01', 15000],
                        [2, '2015-06-01', 1500],
                        [1, '2015-07-01', 15000],
                        [2, '2015-07-01', 1500],
                        [1, '2015-08-01', 15500],
                        [2, '2015-08-01', 1650],
                        [1, '2015-09-01', 15500],
                        [2, '2015-09-01', 1650],
                        [1, '2015-10-01', 16000],
                        [2, '2015-10-01', 1650],
                        [1, '2015-11-01', 16000],
                        [2, '2015-11-01', 1650],
                        [1, '2015-12-01', 16000],
                        [2, '2015-12-01', 1650],
                        [1, '2016-01-01', 16500],
                        [2, '2016-01-01', 1650],
                        [1, '2016-02-01', 16500],
                        [2, '2016-02-01', 1650],
                        [1, '2016-03-01', 17200],
                        [2, '2016-03-01', 1650],
                        [1, '2016-04-01', 17200],
                        [2, '2016-04-01', 1650],
                        [1, '2016-05-01', 17200],
                        [2, '2016-05-01', 1650]])
```

- The first column is the Join column .
- The second is the date
- The 3 is a salary .

I want to join the 3 dataSet and for the Salary column i want to have the average of the past salary for the same ID .

How this can be done using pandas and numpy or even another framework .

Thanks in advance .

===== UPDATE ====

I add here some more simple example of the two dataframe and the expected result :

```
ID  DATE          SALARY
1   2015-01-01    1500    
2   2015-01-01    1000    
1   2015-03-01    1600    
1   2015-04-01    1700    

ID  DATE
1   2015-01-01
2   2015-01-01
1   2015-02-01
2   2015-02-01
1   2015-03-01
2   2015-03-01
1   2015-04-01
2   2015-04-01
```

The expected result :

```
ID  DATE
1   2015-01-01  1500
2   2015-01-01  1000
1   2015-02-01  1500
2   2015-02-01  1000
1   2015-03-01  1550
2   2015-03-01  1000
1   2015-04-01  1600
2   2015-04-01  1000
```

In other term I want to average past salary when merging the 2 datasets

Comment: the data is useful.  I'm still very confused.  please provide an example of what you are looking for.  Also, read this for guidance on how to post  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please see my update with small example

Comment: @Nabil I think there is a mistake in your updated example. The second df doesn't have any salary information, so I don't see where the average would come from.

Comment: The second df is like an empty historical timeseries with no value , the goal is to populate it with salary past aggregation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider an apply function for a conditional running mean:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = '''
ID  DATE          SALARY
1   2015-01-01    1500    
2   2015-01-01    1000    
1   2015-03-01    1600    
1   2015-04-01    1700
'''
df1 = pd.read_table(StringIO(data), sep="\s+", parse_dates=[1])

data = '''
ID  DATE
1   2015-01-01
2   2015-01-01
1   2015-02-01
2   2015-02-01
1   2015-03-01
2   2015-03-01
1   2015-04-01
2   2015-04-01
'''
df2 = pd.read_table(StringIO(data), sep="\s+", parse_dates=[1])

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['ID', 'DATE'], how='outer').sort_values('DATE')\
                                  .reset_index(drop=True)

df['AVGSALARY'] = df.apply(lambda x: np.mean(df[(df['ID'] == x['ID']) & \
                                  (df['DATE'] <= x['DATE'])]['SALARY']), axis=1)    
print(df)

#     ID       DATE  SALARY  AVGSALARY
# 0  1.0 2015-01-01  1500.0     1500.0
# 1  2.0 2015-01-01  1000.0     1000.0
# 2  1.0 2015-02-01     NaN     1500.0
# 3  2.0 2015-02-01     NaN     1000.0
# 4  1.0 2015-03-01  1600.0     1550.0
# 5  2.0 2015-03-01     NaN     1000.0
# 6  1.0 2015-04-01  1700.0     1600.0
# 7  2.0 2015-04-01     NaN     1000.0
```